# ActiveDirectory authentication and extending with custom properties

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I would like to use AD authentication on my web service. This seems to work fine and controller's User property is initialized with claims (ClaimsPrincipal).
Data which I receive from AD it's not enough and I would like to extend the User property with additional information i.e. Department, Manager etc. 
I cannot do that on the AD site.

My questions are:
1. Is there a possibility to extend the User property with additional data collected from local DB?
2. Can I add new roles to ClaimsPrincipal so I could use [Authorize(Roles="MickeyMouse")]? (MickeyMouse it's not returned from AD).

thank you in advance

Comment: Sure, aren’t you able to just add a custom claim on the principal ? Persisting those claims will obviously be your responsibility though ... and then instead of authorize by role, you can authorize by policy, where the policy requirement will include the custom claim you add at login.

Comment: Of course the only problem is that extension properties are not returned in the id token :) There needs to be an additional call to the Graph API after authentication to get those properties and add them as additional claims.